# R.Java don't create

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

R.Java don't create because I have errore in code an I accidentally deleted R.java.

Here is the code:

```
public SwipeyTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.SwipeyTabs, defStyle, 0);

        mBottomBarColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_bottomBarColor,
                mBottomBarColor);
        mBottomBarHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_bottomBarHeight, 2);
        mTabIndicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.styleable.SwipeyTabs_tabIndicatorHeight, 3);

        a.recycle();

        init();



    }
```

And in xml

```
 <com.example.uniradio.SwipeyTabs
    android:id="@+id/swipeytabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff3b3b3b"
    swipeytabs:bottomBarColor="#ff96aa39"
    swipeytabs:bottomBarHeight="2dip"
    swipeytabs:tabIndicatorHeight="3dip" />
```

Now, how do I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do it two ways:

You can either run it from eclipse as suggested here, by going to Project -> Build Project, or simply running a "clean"

[image: build android project]

Or you can try and create an APK of your app via command line, which will then generate the .R files as well as the APK.

If there are any errors, the command line will report it.

To do it via command line, you can run the following:

```
ant release
```

From within your project directory

Answer (score 3):

R file is not being generated, due to error in xml, do as follows to find error,

```
eclipse menu->windows-> show view -> problems
```

and do corrective options.

Comment: in xml  error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'bottomBarHeight' in package'@@@@@@'

Comment: ok if I delete it and run it ok, but when I reinsert it, it's the same.

Comment: its simple yaar, there isnt such attribute for the com.example.uniradio.SwipeyTabs. so dont use that variable.

Comment: after I deleted R.Java it run!

Answer (score 0):

Try these tips.....

**1** First `Clean` the project, from your Eclipse IDE

**2** Please see that there are **no errors** in any of the `.java` files and specially in the `.xml` files.

**3** Please **remove all** the Errors from the `Error logs`; I know this is weird but that's how Eclipse works.

**4** `R.java` file is automatically generated and contains the public static final constants grouped according to their XML resource type.

**5** After you are sure about the 1st , 2nd and 3rd point above, try **deleting** the R.java file, clean the project, after this shutdown your Eclipse. And again open it.

Comment: ok I just do it, but when I reinsert the deleted code, there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem like you. Lest try: Open Android SDK Manager -> reinstall packages Android SDK Platform-Tools and Android SDK Build-Tools in Tools folder.